# Are platformer games, with the camera centred on the character, examples of egocentric vision?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, computer-vision, deep-rl, environment

An example may be [CoinRun](https://github.com/openai/coinrun), where the character sprite is always centred in the camera view, while the environment moves as a result of player input.

To me, this sounds like [egocentric vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egocentric_vision), although the wikipedia page seems to rely heavily on the notion of a wearable camera in the definition, and the treatment seems to ignore 2D environments, directly jumping to the 3D case.

If this (CoinRun, other similar platformers, etc.) is indeed not an example of an egocentric vision problem, what is it an example of? Is there a formal way of expressing the difference between platformers where the camera is centred about the character vs platformers where the camera is centred about the environment?

I am particularly interested in this to help me with formalizing differences in environments in an RL context, where environment state is perceived visually, for example through a CNN.

Answer (score 1):

At the time, this probably referred to what we call an POV or first person view. It was applied to head mounted cameras. This term was developed a long time ago to describe something that didn't have a term for it by researchers slowly getting into virtual experiences.

> naturally approximates the visual field of the camera wearer

If a platformer was 3d and you controlled their field of view. Then it's egocentric.  A platformer like coin run would NOT approximate the runner's field of vision. There is a 3rd person camera following the runner. It is not egocentric.

Comment: Thanks. Any clue for the second part of my question? Is there a formal way of expressing the difference between platformers where the camera is centred about the character vs platformers where the camera is centred about the environment?

Comment: I'm Not entirely sure.
"chase camera" or "follow camera" provides an unambiguous term to describe a third-person camera that follows the player's movements. These terms are widely used in the gaming industry and are well understood by researchers in the field of HCI. 

I can now see how the term ego-centric might apply here. 
Perhaps you can consider using the term ego-centric view with modifiers to the phrase to specify how it's egocentric. `first person ego-centric view` vs `third person ego-centric view`

Comment: thanks. If you integrate this comment into your answer, I'll accept your answer.